# How to change caret color in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How can I change textbox caret color in windows phone 8.1 universal app? in windows phone 8 we used TextBox.CaretBrush to change caret color. But this is missing in windows phone 8.1 WinRt. Is there are way to change caret color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone universal app, we **can't** use CaretBrush any more.

[Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) vs Windows Phone 8.1](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20(Silverlight)-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html)

But we can change background of TextBox when `Focus` and `UnFocus`, So the caret can be seen.