# How to change the select cursor's color for windows phone using xaml or c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I noticed that the color of the cursor(when you select a piece of text in the textbox) and virtual keyboard highlight color are the same. And I want to change the color of cursor to some other color. What should I do? I know that textbox has cursor property (caretbush too), however, I cannot see it in my xaml code. Any suggestions? I noticed that LINE and a few other apps are able to change the default color. I'm wondering how to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change caret color in windows phone 8.1 universal app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617692/how-to-change-caret-color-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app)

Comment: @venerik kind of, but that one actually didn't solve the problem. See the update after the question mark. Thank you for the information though.